# Using multiple conditionals in haproxy use_backend

Tags: haproxy

Without brackets, seems it is not possible to have haproxy select use_backend based on `true and (a or b)`

For example, I want to `use_backend ClusterA if allowed_src and (method_a or path_b)`.  Regardless if I invert the conditions before/after `and`, I am left with a way to hit the backend with a single true value instead of requiring `allowed_src` and one of either `method_a` or `path_b`.

*updated example such that all three ACL are distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer Vadim wrote achieves what you asked initially. To match your updated question, you could use the following logic:

```
acl allowedsrc src 123.123.123.123
acl mypath path_beg /path_a
use_backend ClusterA if allowedsrc mypath || allowedsrc METH_POST
```

Since you didn't mention what you were trying to match with **allowedsrc** ACL, I'll assume you wanted to match certain IP address.

Let me break down the whole logic to plain english.

acl allowedsrc matches source IP 123.123.123.123

acl mypath matches URLs that begins with **/path_a**

The last line means that request will be poined to **ClusterA** backend **if** source IP address was 123.123.123.123 **and** if URL was beginning with /path_a **or** if source IP address was 123.123.123.123 and HTTP method was POST.

Instead of METH_POST, you can use different pre-defined ACLs. Check out [HAProxy's documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.4) to see the complete list.

Comment: That only works if the path_a and path_b use path_beg.  What if one was a path based acl and one was method based.

Comment: In that case, you may want to use something like: use_backend ClusterA if allowedsrc mypath || allowedsrc METH_POST

Instead of METH_POST, you can match different methods (e.g. METH_GET, METH_HEAD, etc.)

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional information. Hopefully it'll help you understand the whole logic.

Comment: Thanks Tubeless.  Does **and** always get evaluated before **or**?

Comment: Found that and does indeed have higher precedence than or: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/10-0/traffic-management/lb-layer7/writing-conditions/

Answer (score 1):

```
acl allowedsrc .......
acl mypath path_beg /path_a /path_b
use_backend ClusterA if allowedsrc mypath
```

Comment: This answer needs an explanation.

Comment: If two acl are not the same (path_beg) this won't work.

Comment: @haproxy-user1997, Vadim gave you a correct answer. Since "mypath" ACL mathes either "/path_a" or "/path_b", it's effectively the same as (path_a or path_b).